# CSV - Microsoft office for mac 2008 doesn't add all the commas?

Tags: macos, microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, csv

Let's say I have 5 column headings and I only complete the first 2 values. I then save the file as CSV (Windows). It ends up looking like this:

```
ID,Product,Name,Value,Interest
1,PC
```

Which is no good because it missed 3 commas.

If I create the same CSV in Excel on a Windows PC it looks ok:

```
ID,Product,Name,Value,Interest
1,PC,,,
```

Unfortunately I don't have access to a MAC. This problem has been experienced by a client of mine which needs CSV for a site.

Comment: The data is null anyway, what's the issue? You want there to be 0s?

Comment: Problem is that the CSV needs to have all the commas otherwise the CSV doesn't work for importing the products for an online shop...

Answer (score 0):

Tell the client to try `save as - windows csv` OR `save as - ms-dos csv`